# UserControl can not use app resources by default

Tags: c#, uwp

I used custom Style for my `UWP` application.I mean I wrote these code in App.xaml

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="ThemeDictionary">
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\BasicStyle.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and in BasicStyle.xaml I wrote my basic styles like

```
     <Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="#B9C5B7" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

when I change some setting of my app I want to load another style file

```
     ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = uri };
     Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].MergedDictionaries[0] = rd;
```

Everything works fine but style for `usercontrol` doesn't work.

I wrote in `BasicStyle.xaml` :

```
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="700"></Setter>
</Style>
```

but it didn't work. I can not define a style in my xaml page and inherit from the default style that I told above because sometimes it  is changed in the middle of application and I don't know what is the default style. as you know other control like `textbox` or `Button` works correct. can somebody tell me what is wrong with `usercontrol` and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, in my xaml I used UserControl tag as a root of tree:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
         xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
   <Grid>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I Change it to sub tree of Page class and it worked:

```
 <Page x:Class="MyView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
     xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<UserControl>
<Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
</Page>
```